# Paging Google Custom Search via XML

Tags: google

I am trying to set up a custom search on my site and just for testing was checking out the search API's. The trouble is that the API do give me the valid results and total number of items found etc, however when I try to go to second page of the search they do not provide me with any data.

Is it because I  have to pay for the custom search engine?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you should be able to get 10 pages of each 10 results max. Perhaps something is wrong with your second request. Do you built it yourself, or do you use the one returned ?

Also, there is a cap of 100 requests per day.

Comment: I build the request myself and I use localhost to test it. If I use a public domain it doesn't work which is understandable.